# Make a new 'Change' column when a value in one column changes wrt to values in 'ID' column

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I need to make a new column 'Change' which updates when the value in 'Feature' column changes for a specfic value in 'ID' column.
The dataframe I have:

```
ID Feature 
1  0
1  0 
1  1
1  1
2  0
2  0
2  1
2  2
```

The resulting dataframe that I want:

```
ID Feature Change
1  0       no_change
1  0       no_change
1  1       change
1  1       no_change
2  0       no_change
2  0       no_change
2  1       change
2  2       change
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare shifted values with back filling missing values per groups for mask and pass to [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask = df.groupby('ID')['Feature'].apply(lambda x: x.shift().bfill()).eq(df['Feature'])
df['Change'] = np.where(mask, 'no_change', 'change')
print (df)
   ID  Feature     Change
0   1        0  no_change
1   1        0  no_change
2   1        1     change
3   1        1  no_change
4   2        0  no_change
5   2        0  no_change
6   2        1     change
7   2        2     change
```

Comment: That does the job. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

You can use group on `ID` column and get the difference from previous row using **[`groupby.diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html)**, fill nulls with 0, and assign where row not equal 0 as `change` and the rest as `no_change`

```
df['Change']  = np.where(df.groupby("ID")['Feature'].diff().fillna(0).ne(0),
                         "change","no_change")
```

---

```
print(df)

   ID  Feature     Change
0   1        0  no_change
1   1        0  no_change
2   1        1     change
3   1        1  no_change
4   2        0  no_change
5   2        0  no_change
6   2        1     change
7   2        2     change
```